# Spring @Transactional method called by multithread(multi-request)

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, transactions

Java web
Spring MVC framework

In my service level, I wrote a `@Transactional` method. In that method, I update some data in database and then read the data from the database later.
What surprises me is that when several requests come, inside the same thread, the data change is visible(which is supposed to be), but the data change is not visible in other thread.
Isn't different threads of one method build as one transaction?
And what should I do if I still want to use transaction and I want the same method called in different threads be in one transaction (the change of the data can be seen by each other)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may want to play with `isolation` parameter of`@Transactional` annotation. Spring by default uses.. hm.. `DEFAULT` which is set by database, so may be different. You can try to use: `READ_UNCOMMITTED`. More info: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-isolation-tutorial

Answer (score 10):

From [*Professional Java for Web Applications* by *Nicholas S. Williams*](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Java-for-Web-Applications.productCd-1118656466.html)

> **Using Threads for Transactions and Entity Managers**

> The transaction scope is limited to the thread the transaction begins in. The transaction manager then links the transaction to managed resources used in the same thread during the life of the transaction. When using the [Java Persistence API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API), the resource you work with is the [`EntityManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html). It is the functional equivalent of Hibernate ORM’s [`Session`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) and JDBC’s [`Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html). Normally, you would obtain an `EntityManager` from the [`EntityManagerFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) before beginning a transaction and performing JPA actions. However, this does not work with the Spring Framework model of managing transactions on your behalf.
> The solution to this problem is the [`org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/SharedEntityManagerBean.html). When you configure JPA in Spring Framework, it creates a `SharedEntityManagerBean` that proxies the `EntityManager` interface. This proxy is then injected into your JPA repositories. When an `EntityManager` method is invoked on this proxy instance, the following happens in the background:

> ➤➤ If the current thread already has a real `EntityManager` with an active transaction, it delegates the call to the method on that `EntityManager`.

> ➤➤ Otherwise, Spring Framework obtains a new `EntityManager` from the
> `EntityManagerFactory`, starts a transaction, and binds both to the current thread. It then delegates the call to the method on that `EntityManager`. When the transaction is either committed or rolled back, Spring unbinds the transaction and the `EntityManager` from the thread and then closes the `EntityManager`. Future `@Transactional` actions on the same thread (even within the same request) start the process over again, obtaining a new `EntityManager` from the factory and beginning a new transaction. This way, no two threads use an `EntityManager` at the same time, and a given thread has only one transaction and one `EntityManager` active at any given time.

(I paraphrased it a little the above piece)

I think its self explanatory and answers your question. But I would like to add that, if you were not to use [Spring MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html) then you would have gotten the session using `SessionFactory` in Hibernate. Hibernate `Session`s represent the life of a transaction from start to finish. Depending on how your application is architected, that might be less than a second or several minutes; and in a web application, it could be one of several transactions in a request, a transaction lasting an entire request, or a transaction spanning multiple requests. A `Session`, which is not thread-safe and must be used **only in one thread** at a time, is responsible for managing the state of entities.